# Set difference in probability

Tags: probability

Do any of these rules apply in probability? Let A and B be events.
$$
P((A \cup B) \backslash B)=P(A\cup B) - P(B)
$$

and
$$
P(A\backslash B) = P(A)-P(B)
$$
I am aware that there seems to be a contradiction since 
  $$  (A \cup B) \backslash B   $$ and 
$$ A\backslash B 
$$
refer to the same set but the probabilities on the RHS might not be equal.

Answer (score 4):

The first is true. $A\cup B\setminus B$ and $B$ are disjoint sets with union $$ (A\cup B \setminus B) \cup B = A\cup B$$ so the probabilities add up $$ P(A\cup B \setminus B) + P(B) = P(A\cup B).$$

The second is false. For instance, let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint events with $P(A) = P(B) = 1/2$ (like for instance $A$ is the event that a coin is flipped heads and $B$ is the event that it is flipped tails). Then $A\setminus B = A$ So the LHS is $1/2$ but the RHS is $0.$

Answer (score 3):

The first one is true, but the second is not true. Let $A\subseteq B$ with $P(B)>P(A)$. In the second equality the l.h. side is nonnegative and the r.h.s. is negative:
$$P(A\backslash B)\geq 0 \text{ whereas } P(A)-P(B)<0.$$

The following equality is true: if $C\subseteq D$ then $P(D\setminus C)=P(D)-P(C)$. Apply it:
$$
P((A\cup B)\setminus B)=P(A\cup B)-P(B)
$$
since $B\subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: Could you give me bit of an explanation why the first one is true? I could not find the formula anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: @matt With pleasure. See edited answer.